# Can't boot 64 bit with newly installed ram

Tags: boot, 64-bit

I was using win-7 64 bit with 2GB ram. Then i added one 4GB along with it. Both ram are of same brand. The system is not booting after the installation. Its working fine when i reinstalled with 32-bit win-7. When i try to install 64 bit with a boot CD the system keeps on restarting soon after the boot CD loads and shows "preparing" screen. I have also tried win-8.1 x64 and ubuntu x64 still it keeps on restarting. What is the problem?

SYSTEM SPEC

- intel core i3 540
- 3.07 GHz
- intel DH55PJ mother board
- DDR3 ZION RAM
- slot#1 2GB slot#2 4GB

Comment: Does it boot with only the 4gb?

Comment: No its not booting with 4GB alone

Comment: Sounds like a faulty or incompatible ram if it doesn't boot with 4 GB alone. Check if your mainboard is compatible with the specs of your new RAM (Clock speed, memory tech etc.) and see if there is any updates for your BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Your motherboard supports up to 8 GB of RAM on 2 modules, so you should be able to install your new ram module: http://ark.intel.com/products/48955/Intel-Desktop-Board-DH55PJ

It seems to me the new ram module is faulty (it may happen even with new components). Did you try a memtest? It should be available on Ubuntu installation media, otherwise you can download it from http://www.memtest.org

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use RAM frequency  bigger than you can use on your laptop. (I think that you have problem on your laptop) 
For example **RAM** with **1600** can be used as **1333** or **1067** but it has some limitation and for some reason **on some laptops you can't use this options with less frequency.**
It will works for some time (not more then 30 minutes) than you will have kernel panic. (For all OS, live CD's or etc.)
So solution will be to replace RAM to your frequency.

And one more reason: new RAM could be broken.

Comment: So the problem is with my RAM frequency. When i checked the RAM with CPU-Z, one ram has higher frequency.. so how can make it same? Either i have to overclock the one with low frequency or reduce the frequency of the other. How to do that?